# SoapUI: response with CDATA is giving null. searched various article but no luck

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

Hello I have below SOAP reponse.

`

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetWeatherResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetWeatherResult><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<CurrentWeather>
  <Location>Cape Town, Cape Town International Airport, South Africa (FACT) 33-59S 018-36E 0M</Location>
  <Time>Jun 04, 2016 - 05:00 AM EDT / 2016.06.04 0900 UTC</Time>
  <Wind> from the SE (130 degrees) at 21 MPH (18 KT):0</Wind>
  <Visibility> greater than 7 mile(s):0</Visibility>
  <SkyConditions> mostly clear</SkyConditions>
  <Temperature> 60 F (16 C)</Temperature>
  <DewPoint> 44 F (7 C)</DewPoint>
  <RelativeHumidity> 55%</RelativeHumidity>
  <Pressure> 30.39 in. Hg (1029 hPa)</Pressure>
  <Status>Success</Status>
</CurrentWeather>]]></GetWeatherResult>
      </GetWeatherResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"`
```

for the following request: http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx.

I want to read XML Data in above response using script. but it is giving null.

I have tried script as below

> def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
>   def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContent)
>   holder.namespaces["ns"] = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/" def
>   weatherinfo= holder.getNodeValue("//ns:GetWeatherResult/text()")
>   log.info weatherinfo

bit Instead of getting above reponse I am getting NULL. I have read the SOAPUI documentation on CDATA but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer. It was just one extra slash in namespace that was giving me null.

Both the below scripts are working now.

```
> def respXmlHolder = new
> com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(messageExchange.getResponseContentAsXml())
> respXmlHolder.namespaces["ns1"] ="http://www.webserviceX.NET" def
> CDATAXml= respXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//ns1:GetWeatherResult/text()")
> log.info CDATAXml

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContent)
holder.namespaces["ns"] = "http://www.webserviceX.NET"
def weatherinfo= holder.getNodeValue("//ns:GetWeatherResult/text()")
log.info weatherinfo
```